# I get the ' is not a function ' error in the store while trying to saveState into localStorage

Tags: redux, react-redux, store

I was working with this tutorial 
https://medium.com/@jrcreencia/persisting-redux-state-to-local-storage-f81eb0b90e7e
because I need to save the state of my button into local storage. I was following the steps 1:1 but at the very end I got this problem: 
[image: re]

Comment: to not confuse you: 
open: store.saveState().open is the equivalent of todos: store.saveState().todos 
and it comes from Islbutton.
state: {
open: false,
role: ""
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the persistedState is null the first time you run the app. Try to change `persistedState` with `persistedState || {}`

Comment: I did let store = createStore(rootReducer, persistedState || {}, .... and still the same